# I keep getting a "File Not Found" error in my Delphi code. But I have my Text file and Delphi project in the same folder

Tags: delphi, file-not-found

```
var
  Tour:Textfile;
begin
  AssignFile(Tour,'Toets.txt' );
  Append(Tour);
  Writeln(Tour,'Test');
  CloseFile(Tour);
end;
```

I don't understand why it gives the "File Not Found" error, because the text file (Toets.txt) is in the same folder as the Delphi project. I even opened and coded a new Delphi project but I got the same results. What should I do?

Comment: By default, Delphi projects are compiled to .\$(Platform)\$(Config) folder - in the case of Windows 32-bit, in Debug config this translates to \Win32\Debug. If the binary is being executed from there, and your text file is in the root of the project source, using AssignFile like that will not find the file. The simplest solution is to copy the text file to the project output folder

Comment: So should I enter the Toets.txt Text file into the project output folder and delete the .\$(Platform)\$(Config) an see if that works?

Comment: Please read the last sentence from @DaveNottage's comment again!

Comment: And please use absolute paths to open files, because it is not guaranteed to work every time due to the so called "working dir"! Use this: ``ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0)) + 'Toets.txt'``

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72924690/fileexists-returning-false